# PowerPoint 2007: Snapping still happening even after turning off

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, snapping

I'm hoping someone here can help me because it's very annoying and time consuming to get done what I need to accomplish when the program acts up. You'd think that shutting off snap to grid and to other objects would do something? This is 2017 now, that's 10 years since I bought my PowerPoint 2007 so I'm hoping someone has figured out how to fix this problem.

What's happening is when I create a paste special object (Kinda like clip art) of a few lines and circles and then try to join lines to that clip art the line ends up having a mind of it's own and goes wherever it wants to and has a red dot on the end of the line.

Does anyone have a solution that will correct this abnormality?

Comment: I've never been able to position  precisely in PowerPoint. To align I have to draw a guide and bump up to it. I gave no cure but I can commiserate.  I suspect there's hidden formatting so it can output to html or something.

Answer (score 0):

Clipart objects have smart connection points that maybe are your magnets. You can neuter the clipart by cutting it into the clipboard and pasting it back as PNG or EMF.